# Multiple ajax requests writing on same file.

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

In my application, I am using multiple ajax requests which write to an XML file. Ajax requests are fired on certain events(like a div's offsettop being equal to certain value) so their timing cannot be exactly predicted. It is also possible that both requests fire at the same time. My question is, if they both fire at the same time and try to write to the same XML file, do you think it would create a conflict which will not allow the file to be open by two requests. Because, in my case I am getting an error saying :

**( ! ) Warning: SimpleXMLElement::asXML(withbabu.xml) [simplexmlelement.asxml]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument**

I know this error comes when the filename is wrong or the file doesnt exist, but in my case the same request is able to run many times the same lines of code and only sometimes, it returns this error. So, I am sure that something is happening behind the scenes. As I am using multiple ajax requests writing to the same file so I thought, this could be the reason for this error. Please provide your answer if you know what could be the solution to this.

The error is coming on this line:

```
$filename = "with".$SESSION['user'];
$xml->asXML($filename.'.xml');       // error shows its line number here.
```

Just as an introduction, this is similar to a gaming application and is firing multiple ajax requests based on certain events.

Thank you so much for your time to review my question.

Cheers.

Comment: Accessing the same file should of course be synchronized! Using sessions (session_start()) in your php script, however, serializes the concurrent requests for each session; and so should already do this synchronization for you..

Comment: have you checked the resulting filename in the cases of the error? maybe it is an invalid filename (due to special chars in the user name?)

Comment: The name of the file is always the same and is dependent on current session logged in user. It works most of the times. Lets say, the same code works 100 times and fails one time. During ajax requests... I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to crate an xml object before using `asXML`. Do this:

```
$filename = "with".$SESSION['user'];
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement();
$xml->asXML($filename.'.xml');
```

Comment: dear, I was showing the code in short. I have created that in the beginning of the file..

Comment: $xml =new SimpleXMLElement($filename.'.xml', null, true);
    
    $lastid = $xml->xpath("/game/otherchars/lastid");
 $lastid = (int)$lastid[0];
 $otherchars = $xml->xpath("/game/otherchars/char");
 
 $limit = 0;
 
 
 for($i=0;$i<sizeof($otherchars);$i++)
 {
  
    if($limit < 2)
    {
    //echo "<br> new time ";
     //print_r($otherchars[$i]); 
    $char = $otherchars[$i]->name;
   
    $total = (int)$otherchars[$i]->total;
    $gone = (int)$otherchars[$i]->gone;
    
    $looptill = $total - $gone;

Comment: for($j=0;$j<$looptill;$j++)
    {  
      //echo "<br> looping ";
    $charid = "char".$lastid;
          $top = rand(100, 300);  
           
          echo "<div id = '$charid' class='othercharclass' data-dir='down' data-animating='false' style='top: $top"."px; position: absolute; "."left: 0px;'>".$char."</div>";
        //  echo "<div class='othercharclass'> $char </div>";   
    $otherchars[$i]->gone = (int)$otherchars[$i]->gone + 1;
    $xml->asXML($filename.'.xml');

Comment: echo "<script> 
       setanim('$lastid'); 
    </script>";
  
    $lastid = $lastid + 1;
    $ocref = $xml->xpath("/game/otherchars");
    $ocref[0]->lastid = $lastid;
    $xml->asXML($filename.'.xml');
   // print_r($otherchars[$i]); 
    $limit = $limit + 1;
    
     
      }
 }

Comment: $curruser = $_SESSION['user'];

$filename = "with".$curruser;   This is how $filename is initialised.

Comment: in your link above where is `$filename` declared?

Comment: $filename was at the very top... It is $filename = "with".$_SESSION['user']

Comment: why do you write the file twice (line 37 and 48)?

Comment: and: why do you at all write the file inside the loop(s)??